# Do Python and Matlab have the "config object" in Javascript to implement an object and initialize an instance?

Tags: javascript, python, matlab, object, config

In Javascript, I noticed that there is a method to implement an object and initialize an instance. It seems very handy, and they seem calling it "config object".

```
// Implement
var Button = function(config) {
    this.x = config.x || 0;
    this.y = config.y || 0;
    this.width = config.width || 150;
    this.height = config.height || 50;
    this.label = config.label || "Click";
};
// Initialize
var btn1 = new Button({x: 100, y: 100, label: "Please click!"});
```

Is there any similar way to do this in Python and Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

What you are in fact referring to, is defining and constructing a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)). That can be a bit of a mouthful. [This is a bit easier on the mind](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) and is written for Python. [Here's the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/getting-familiar-with-classes.html) for classes in Matlab.

While Python, C++, Java and many other [object-oriented programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) are fundamentally designed with classes, JavaScript doesn't have classes and all the [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) that comes with them. In your example, you are simply defining a function that takes a [JavaScript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) as its only argument, and assigns the object properties to a special containing object called `this`. In Python, `this` is called `self` instead, which is a much better term for it.

In a nutshell, a class is like a mold that when an object is constructed out of it, it retains some properties that are unique to itself (totally over-simplified)

Consider the following pseudo-code:

```
class Person()
    constructor(name)
        self.name = name
```

This is the mold. We can now initialize multiple instances of `Person`, each with different names.

```
>>> person1 = Person("Tim")
>>> person2 = Person("Mary")
>>> person1.name
"Tim"
>>> person2.name
"Mary"
```

This way you can write common functionality for a `Person` such as a `talk` method.

```
class Person():
   constructor(name):
       self.name = name

   talk(message):
       print(message)
```

Now both Tim and Mary can talk to eachother

```
>>> person1.talk('Hello!')
"Hello"
>>> person2.talk("Greetings!")
"Greetings!"
```

I highly recommend playing around in the [Python shell](https://www.python.org/shell/), or writing a few scripts and running them see how you define and initialize classes. Hopefully this will get the ball rolling for you.